# Get command line parameter as spring batch job parameters for @Scheduled spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

Below is my spring boot main class , where I have `@Scheduled` beans

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.mypackage" })
public class MyMain {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication.run(MyMain.class, args);
    }


    @Scheduled(cron = "0 00 05 * * ?")
    private void perform() throws Exception {
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }
}
```

I will be receiving parameters from command line which I need to put as job parameters . How can I achieve the same as `@Scheduled` annotated methods does not take in any parameter.

Comment: How should this work? Your scheduled method runs without interaction. What kind of parameters would you need?

Answer (score 4):

You can inject a bean of type `ApplicationArguments` and use it to get application arguments:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyMain {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationArguments applicationArguments;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MyMain.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 00 05 * * ?")
    private void perform() throws Exception {
        String[] sourceArgs = applicationArguments.getSourceArgs();
        JobParameters jobParameters; // create job parameters from sourceArgs
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    }
}
```

You can find more details about the `ApplicationArguments` type in the [Accessing Application Arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-arguments) section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using ApplicationArguments is a good hint; was helpful for me. Thanks.