# How to launch from the command line a spring batch located inside a spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm working with spring boot 2.3 and I've some spring batch configurations inside it.

Currently if I want to run a spring batch process I've used the following approach

Spring batch job configuration

```
@Configuration("myJobConf")
@JobReference("myJob")
public class MyJob
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: true
      names: ${JOB_NAME}
```

And when I want to launch the spring batch process from the command line I run

```
java -jar mySpringBootApplication.jar -DJOB_NAME=myJob
```

But now I need to pass some job parameters also.
How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get command line parameter as spring batch job parameters for @Scheduled spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53064804/get-command-line-parameter-as-spring-batch-job-parameters-for-scheduled-spring)

Comment: I added an answer. Does it help?

Comment: That exactly what I need. I've searched in the spring batch documentation, but not in the spring boot one. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But now I need to pass some job parameters also. How can I do that?

You can pass job parameters as key/value pairs:

```
java -jar mySpringBootApplication.jar -DJOB_NAME=myJob param1=value1 param2=value2
```

You can find more details in the [Batch Applications -> Running from the Command Line](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html#howto-spring-batch-running-command-line) section of the reference documentation.